# Returning elements of a set in Java using toString() method on separate lines

Tags: java, set, tostring

I am using a `toString()` method to return elements of `Set<String>` in Java, but with each element on a separate line.

An example of the code:

```
import java.util.Set;

public class Animals{
    Set<String> animals;
    String newanimal;

    public Anmimals (Set<String> animals){
        this.animals = animals;
        }

    public setAnimals(String newanimal){
        this.newanimal = newanimal;
        animals.add(newanimal);
    }

    public String toString(){
        /* this is where my problem is i want to return the set (below), 
           however i also need each animal to be on a new line */
        return animal
    }

}
```

The only things that I could find that were slightly useful, all ended up suggesting to not use `toString()` and instead use an actual class with `System.out.println()` to print out the information, however, `toString()` is required for this particular problem.

Is it possible to add a for loop to the method and iterate through each method as I return each element of a separate line using `\n` ? All suggestions are welcome, as this one, even if it is possible, seems to be really messy.

Comment: Some code please.

Comment: See edited question

Comment: Now your question makes more sense. Both posted answers are wrong. I will update mine.

Comment: Actually, the other guy's answer is not wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of mistakes in your code.

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Animals{
    Set<String> animals;
    //String newanimal; delete this!

    //Constructor allows users to set animals using a set.
    public Animals (Set<String> animals){
        this.animals = animals;
        }

    //This default constructor is needed because you did not do Set<String> animals = new HashSet();
    public Animals()
    {
        this.animals = new HashSet();
    }

    //This method adds new elements to the animal set. What you did is wrong, so look over and compare
    public void setAnimals(String newanimal){
        animals.add(newanimal);
    }

    //The toString method you were asking about. I used StringBuilder but you can use someString += item + "\n".
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        /* this is where my problem is i want to return the set (below), 
           however i also need each animal to be on a new line */
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for(String item : animals)
        {
            stringBuilder.append(item).append("\n");
        }

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: The toString() section makes sense, however I was hoping you could elaborate on my mistake earlier in the code. How does 
public Animals()
    {
        this.animals = new HashSet();
    }
improve the code or make it different to what I originally had? I'm still learning this and am trying to understand the correct ways to write this code

Comment: Using your old code try `Animals a1 = new Animals(); a1.add("cow");` in your `Main`.

Comment: Or try `Animals a1 = new Animals("cow"); a1.add("pig"); a1.add("chicken"); System.out.println(a.toString());`

Answer (score 3):

I'd stream the set, convert each element to a String and join them with a line separator:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return animals.stream()
                  .map(Object::toString)
                  .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
}
```

**EDIT:**

With the question edited, it was made clear that the question is about joining a `Set<String>`, and not any old `Set`. In this case, the solution can be substantially simplified:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.join(System.lineSeparator(), animals);
}
```